# Getting the host ID and network ID from an IP address

Tags: networking

I'm learning about IP addressing, and I'm still a bit confused. I know that an IP address consists of a network and host ID. To test this in the real world, I googled "what is my IP address" on my tablet and smartphone, both connected to my home wireless network and I got the same IP address. Shouldn't they be different since they are two different hosts? I suspect this has to do with public and private IP addresses, but then, my bigger question is how does data really get to my individual device?

Comment: NAT: network address translation: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat1.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the outside "internet", your IP address is just the IP of your router, provided by your ISP. Within your home network, you have a set of private addresses assigned by your router. The way that programs know to communicate with the correct device is usually through a custom reply-to port that the router re-assigns to packets from each device. This is called NAT.

For example, if you are browsing on port 80 from your tablet and your laptop at the same time, your reply-to port may be set to 3245 for the tablet and 3246 for the laptop. When the router receives a packet going from port 80 to port 3245, it changes 3245 to 80 and sends it to  your tablet. If the port is 3246, it sends it to your laptop instead. The key point here is that the website you are communicating only knows the IP of your home router. As far as those sites are concerned, there are no other devices.

Answer (score 1):

> To test this in the real world, I googled "what is my IP address" on my tablet and smartphone, both connected to my home wireless network and I got the same IP address. Shouldn't they be different since they are two different hosts?

No, because of NAT.

> I suspect this has to do with public and private IP addresses, but then, my bigger question is how does data really get to my individual device?

Thanks to NAT.